# vs solution not finding [Fact] unit tests

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, xunit

I have a VS2017 Pro solution with a Tests class containing all unit tests (decorated with [Fact]). For some reason, VS isn't discovering these tests. Several tests were added by a previous developer and I just added a new test. I asked the previous developer and he said that there might be a mismatch in test runners in my local solution. What steps can I take to try to fix this?
­­­­­­­­­­

Comment: Also make sure that the test classes and test methods are public otherwise the test runner wont be able to see them. Show a [mcve] of the tests in question.

Comment: Have you compiled your test project after adding your new tests ?

Comment: @Subbu yes I compiled the project after adding the new unit test

Comment: @Nkosi - All the tests run on the other developers machine so it seems to have something to do with my environment configuration.  How can I configure the test runner to be used by my solution?